# Unspecified Fields in Overloading constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

I've to intiliaze a class with 7 parameters. Whereas i do have some default values in cases where some of the values are not specified. So, by the overloading constructor method, I'd have to make around 2^7 constructors. Is there any method where i can check which fields are specified in a constructor and set undefined directly to defaults?

Comment: IMO, that many constructors is a sure sign of a flawed design.

Comment: You should probably use the Builder pattern instead of trying to use many constructors.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is not method for it. Luckily you don't need another method for it. Just pass the default values when some parameter don't have any spefic value to pass.